# EF 6 Code First Mapping one-to-many

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, code-first

Can someone please help me with mapping the following hierarchy with EF 6 code first? I can find anything useful for the below example in the documentation.

```
namespace Contacts {
    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            this.Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            this.Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    }


    public class Email
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string TargetId { get; set; }
        public string TargetType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TargetType can be set to Company or Person depending on the entity that contains the Email instance.

DB Schema:

[image]

Comment: You need to let `Company` and `Person` inherit from `TargetType`? Now they are two completely different objects, you need to give them something in common.

Comment: An Email that belongs to Company with Id 2 will have a TargetId = 2 and TargetType = Company and for an Email that belongs to a Person having Id = 5 will have a TargetId = 5 and TargetType = Person. I wanted to have a single table that stores all the emails for Persons and Companies.